# Why is there such a difference between the model and model.eval() for the same input data?

Tags: pytorch

```
import torch
from models.Unets import Unet_dict, NestedUNet, U_Net, R2U_Net, AttU_Net, R2AttU_Net
from copy import deepcopy

model_Inputs = [U_Net, R2U_Net, AttU_Net, R2AttU_Net, NestedUNet]

def model_unet(model_input, in_channel=3, out_channel=1):
    model_test = model_input(in_channel, out_channel)
    return model_test


input_ = torch.randn(32, 3, 128, 128).cuda()
model = model_unet(model_Inputs[3], 3, 156).cuda()
model_ = deepcopy(model)
model_.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    print(torch.sum(torch.abs(model_(input_) - model(input_))))
```

output: tensor(25810780., device='cuda:0')

Why is there such a difference between the model and model_ for the same input data?

I want to test/valid for the model, what should I do?

Comment: It's impossible without seeing the code for the model. Sometimes models have different behaviours at train/test time, such as batch norm, dropout, and train-time-augmentations (last one likely not happening here). Your difference is about 0.3/pixel, which may or may not be significant.